# Jackson JSON deserialization using JsonParser is skipping the first key value pair due to condition check

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind, jackson2

I am using Jackson to deserialize a JSON. The input JSON can be of 2 types `CustomerDocument` or `Single Customer`. `CustomerDocument` will have a `CustomerList` which can consist of a huge number of `Customer` and the `Single Customer` will have just a `Single Customer`. Hence, the Jackson has to handle 2 things:

1. Identify if the provided JSON is a `CustomerDocument`, if so then deserialize the elements in `CustomerList` one by one rather than storing the whole thing into `List` so as to reduce the memory usage.
2. Identify if the provided JSON is a `single Customer` and if so then deserialize the `customer` directly.

I am able to achieve this and everything is working as expected but when I provide the `CustomerDocument` then it's unable to read the `@Context` key-value pair as it has been already read during the check for single `Customer` (as mentioned by you in point 2). I guess the below code would make the problems clear:

Following is the JSON I am trying to deserialize:

```
{
  "@context": [
    "https://stackoverflow.com",
    {
      "example": "https://example.com"
    }
  ],
  "isA": "CustomerDocument",
  "customerList": [
    {
      "isA": "Customer",
      "name": "Batman",
      "age": "2008"
    }
  ]
}
```

Following is my Customer POJO class:

```
@Data
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, visible = true, property = "isA")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Customer implements BaseResponse {
    private String isA;
    private String name;
    private String age;
}


@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, visible = true, property = "isA")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Customer.class, name = "Customer")})
interface BaseResponse {
}
```

Following is my `Main` class which will read the `JSON InputStream` and make the decision whether the provided input JSON is `CustomerList` or `Single Customer` and then deserialize accordingly:

```
public class JacksonMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final InputStream jsonStream = JacksonMain.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Customer.json");
        final JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonFactory().createParser(jsonStream);
        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        jsonParser.setCodec(objectMapper);

        //Goto the start of the document
        jsonParser.nextToken();

        try {
            BaseResponse baseResponse = objectMapper.readValue(jsonParser, BaseResponse.class);
            System.out.println("SINGLE EVENT INPUT" + baseResponse.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("LIST OF CUSTOMER INPUT");
            //Go until the customerList has been reached
            while (!jsonParser.getText().equals("customerList")) {
                System.out.println("Current Token Name : " + jsonParser.getCurrentName());
                if (jsonParser.getCurrentName() != null && jsonParser.getCurrentName().equalsIgnoreCase("@context")) {
                    System.out.println("WITHIN CONTEXT");
                }
                jsonParser.nextToken();
            }
            jsonParser.nextToken();

            //Loop through each object within the customerList and deserilize them
            while (jsonParser.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_ARRAY) {
                final JsonNode customerNode = jsonParser.readValueAsTree();
                final String eventType = customerNode.get("isA").asText();
                Object event = objectMapper.treeToValue(customerNode, BaseResponse.class);
                System.out.println(event.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Following is the output I am getting:

```
LIST OF CUSTOMER INPUT
Current Token Name : isA
Customer(isA=Customer, name=Batman, age=2008)
```

As we can see it's printing only `Current Token Name: isA` I would expect it to print `isA` and `@Context` because it's present before the `isA`. But I am aware that it's not printing because it has already passed that due to the following line of code in `try` block:

```
BaseResponse baseResponse = objectMapper.readValue(jsonParser, BaseResponse.class);
```

Following is a `Single Customer` JSON (just for the reference and this is working fine):

```
{
  "@context": [
    "https://stackoverflow.com",
    {
      "example": "https://example.com"
    }
  ],
  "isA": "Customer",
  "name": "Batman",
  "age": "2008"
}
```

Can someone please suggest to me how can I achieve this and is there a better workaround for this issue?

Please note:

1. The `CustomerList` can have a lot of `Customers` hence I do not want to store the whole `CustomerList` into some `List` as it can take a lot of memories. Hence, I am using `JsonParser` so I can read one `JsonToken` at a time.
2. Also, I do not want to create a `CustomerList` class rather than that I want to read one `Customer` at a time and deserialize it.
3. The JSON structure cannot be modified as it's coming from another application and it's a standard format for my application.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the code, I removed the catch block. `CUSTOMERS_LIST` property differentiate between single and multiple customers.

**JacksonMain.java**

```
   public class JacksonMain {

    private static final String CUSTOMERS_LIST = "customerList";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final InputStream jsonStream = JacksonMain.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Customers.json");
        final JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonFactory().createParser(jsonStream);
        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        jsonParser.setCodec(objectMapper);

        TreeNode treeNode = objectMapper.readTree(jsonParser);
        if (Objects.isNull(treeNode.get(CUSTOMERS_LIST))) {
            BaseResponse baseResponse = objectMapper.treeToValue(treeNode, BaseResponse.class);
            System.out.println("SINGLE EVENT INPUT: " + baseResponse);
        } else {
            System.out.println("LIST OF CUSTOMER INPUT");
            ArrayNode customerList = (ArrayNode) treeNode.get(CUSTOMERS_LIST);
            for (JsonNode node : customerList) {
                BaseResponse event = objectMapper.treeToValue(node, BaseResponse.class);
                System.out.println(event.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have created two resources json files

**Customer.json**

```
{
  "@context": [
    "https://stackoverflow.com",
    {
      "example": "https://example.com"
    }
  ],
  "isA": "Customer",
  "name": "Batman",
  "age": "2008"
}
```

**Customers.json**

```
{
  "@context": [
    "https://stackoverflow.com",
    {
      "example": "https://example.com"
    }
  ],
  "isA": "CustomerDocument",
  "customerList": [
    {
      "isA": "Customer",
      "name": "Batman",
      "age": "2008"
    }
  ]
}
```

**CustomerDocument.java**

```
@Data
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, visible = true, property = "isA")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@ToString
public class CustomerDocument implements BaseResponse {
    @JsonProperty
    private String isA;
    @JsonProperty(value="name")
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty(value="age")
    private String age;
}
```

**Customer.java**

```
@Data
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, visible = true, property = "isA")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Customer implements BaseResponse {
    private String isA;
    private String name;
    private String age;
}
```

**BaseResponse.java**

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, visible = true, property = "isA")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Customer.class, name = "Customer"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = CustomerDocument.class, name = "CustomerDocument")})
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
interface BaseResponse {
}
```

In interface I have added JsonIgnoreProperties annotation and I have added one more missed JsonSubType. [CustomerDocument]

Both cases are working now.

**Performance tests:**

```
Size: 1,065,065 records / customers handled 
Time in seconds: 30.208
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am able to understand how you are achieving this. But I have one doubt previously I was using the following code line`final JsonNode customerNode = jsonParser.readValueAsTree();` to read the one customer at a time from the `CustomerList`. This guaranteed me that I will always have only one `Customer` at a time in memory but in the code, you have provided you are storing the complete `CustomerList` into `ArrayNode customerList`. Wouldnt this store the whole `CustomerList`? The `CustomerList` can have a huge number of `Customers` so it might impact the performance.

Comment: I am not an expert on Java or Jackson hence want to get confirmation on this. Is there any way to avoid this storing of complete `CustomerList`? Because that is also part of my requirement, I should have only one `Customer` at a time in memory during the execution. This requirement is kind of conflicting with my other requirement (differentiating b/w `CustomerDocument` and `Single Customer`). Please guide me on this and provide some workaround or suggestions that can be used this code work as per the requirement. Thanks a lot in advance and looking forward to your suggestions.

Comment: How many records should be handled in single request?

Comment: Thanks for your response and for helping me with the issue. If there is a `CustomerList` then it can have 1000s or 10000s of `Customer` in that so I want to ensure that at a time there is only one `Customer` in memory. Meaning that I would like to read one `Customer` at a time and move to the next one rather than storing the complete `CustomerList` into memory and then traversing over it. In the code, I have provided in the question I am doing something similar but the problem is that I am missing out on the information contained within `@context` so trying to achieve both now. Any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I was able to get it working, Instead of reading the `@context` in `catch` block I tried reading it before the `try-catch`.

```
public class JacksonMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final InputStream jsonStream = JacksonMain.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Customer.json");
        final JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonFactory().createParser(jsonStream);
        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        jsonParser.setCodec(objectMapper);

        //Goto the start of the document
        jsonParser.nextToken();

        //Go until the customerList has been reached
        while (!jsonParser.getText().equals("isA")) {
            System.out.println("Current Token Name : " + jsonParser.getCurrentName());
            if (jsonParser.getCurrentName() != null && jsonParser.getCurrentName().equalsIgnoreCase("@context")) {
                System.out.println("WITHIN CONTEXT");
            }
            jsonParser.nextToken();
        }

        try {
            BaseResponse baseResponse = objectMapper.readValue(jsonParser, BaseResponse.class);
            System.out.println("SINGLE EVENT INPUT" + baseResponse.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("LIST OF CUSTOMER INPUT");

            //Loop through each object within the customerList and deserilize them
            while (jsonParser.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_ARRAY) {
                final JsonNode customerNode = jsonParser.readValueAsTree();
                final String eventType = customerNode.get("isA").asText();
                Object event = objectMapper.treeToValue(customerNode, BaseResponse.class);
                System.out.println(event.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```